# Javascript & JQuery: promises executing in unexpected order

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, promise, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get an array of objects from two different functions. Those functions perform some queries in a database.

I think the problem has to do with the asynchronous nature of transactions.

I have tried several alternatives to try making all the procedure synchronous with no success.

I'll detail the pieces of code that are generating the object:

The expected object shape:

```
[
    {
        row: 
             {
                 prit_cd_item: 7,
                 prit_st_name: "1105 - Jazzboat"
             },
        tariffs:
             [
                 {
                     cdPricing: 14,
                     dsPricing: "Operator tariff"
                 }
             ]
    }
]
```

Function getTariffByProductItem:

```
getTariffByProductItem: function(productItemId) {
    // Return Array of tariffs
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    var tariffs = [];
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('select pric.pric_cd_pricing, pric.pric_ds_pricing ' + 
                        'from tga_pricings pric ' +
                        'where date(\'now\') <= pric.pric_dt_valid_to ' +
                        'and date(\'now\') >= pric.pric_dt_valid_from ' +
                        'and pric.pric_cd_product_item = ?',
        [productItemId],
        function(tx,dbResult) {
            if(dbResult.rows.length) {
                for(var i = 0; i < dbResult.rows.length; i++) {
                    tariffs.push( 
                        {
                            cdPricing: dbResult.rows.item(i).pric_cd_pricing,
                            dsPricing: dbResult.rows.item(i).pric_ds_pricing
                        }
                    );
                }
                def.resolve(tariffs);   
            }
        });
    }
    , function(e) { 
        alert("There has been an error: " + e.message); 
        def.reject();
    });

    return def.promise();
}
```

Function editBookPaxBuyPrepare:

```
editBookPaxBuyPrepare: function(productId) {
var def = new $.Deferred();
var bookingId = $( '#edit-book-pax-pricing-form' ).data('bookid');
var paxId = $( '#edit-book-pax-pricing-form' ).data('paxid');
var productItems = [];

// Check for actual data
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    // Get product items for product
    tx.executeSql('select prit.prit_cd_item, prit.prit_st_name ' +
                    'from tga_products_catalog prod ' +
                    'inner join tga_product_items prit ' +
                    'on prit.prit_cd_product = prod.prod_cd_product ' +
                    'where prod.prod_cd_product = ?',
    [ productId ],
    function(tx, dbResult) {
        if(dbResult.rows.length) {
            // Set form action to EDIT
            $('#edit-book-pax-buy-form').data('formaction', 'edit');
            // Set product name label
            $('#edit-book-pax-buy-product').text(dbResult.rows.item(0).prod_ds_product);
            for(var i=0; i<dbResult.rows.length; i++) {
                // For each producItem get tariffs
                var dbRow = dbResult.rows.item(i);  
                var data = [];

                $.when(bookings.getTariffByProductItem(dbRow.prit_cd_item))
                .then(function(data) {
                    console.log("Product Item: " + dbRow.prit_st_name + " - tariffsArray: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    productItems.push({ "row": dbRow, "tariffs": data });
                });
            }
            def.resolve(productItems);
        }   
    });

},
function(e) {
    def.reject(e);
});
return def.promise();
```

}

Main code calling both above functions:

```
var listFieldset = $( '#edit-book-pax-buy-form-product-items-list' );
listFieldset.empty();
$.when(bookings.editBookPaxBuyPrepare(productId))
.done(function(productItems) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(productItems));
    $( "#edit-book-pax-buy-product-item" ).tmpl( productItems ).appendTo( listFieldset );
    listFieldset.trigger('create');
    listFieldset.listview('refresh');
});
```

The log I get:

```
bookings.js:738 []
2014-11-23 20:03:06.151bookings.js:566 Product Item: 1105 - Local guide - tariffsArray: [{"cdPricing":7,"dsPricing":"Operator tariff"}]
2014-11-23 20:03:06.155bookings.js:566 Product Item: 1105 - Local guide - tariffsArray: [{"cdPricing":14,"dsPricing":"Operator tariff"}]
2014-11-23 20:03:06.159bookings.js:566 Product Item: 1105 - Local guide - tariffsArray: [{"cdPricing":15,"dsPricing":"Operator tariff"}]
2014-11-23 20:03:06.163bookings.js:566 Product Item: 1105 - Local guide - tariffsArray: [{"cdPricing":16,"dsPricing":"Operator tariff"}]
```

As you can see, "console.log(JSON.stringify(productItems));" is executed BEFORE the console.log line in the loop inside editBookPaxBuyPrepare function. The expected behaviour is the other way round: wait until editBookPaxBuyPrepare finishes and then log the contents of the returndes array in the promise.

What I expect is:

- call editBookPaxBuyPrepare, get product items (one on each row).
- For every row (product item), get array of tariffs calling to getTariffByProductItem on each for loop iteration.
- When the object is correctly created, go back to the main program.

I need some good eyes to help me with this.

Any help is welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate to [Javascript Promises not executing correctly.Two objects in JQuery tmpl using {{each …}}.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26994436/1960455) ? It is not obvious what the difference between those to questions is.

Comment: I understand your comment. It is not really a duplicate, but it is related. When I published the other question I thought it was related to jQuery-tmpl. As I wasn't receiving any feedback I rewrited it with the new approach. I understand this shouldn't be done.

Comment: This is not causing a problem, but is worth knowing.  You can just do `bookings.editBookPaxBuyPrepare(productId).done(...)`.  You don't need `$.when()` around it.  `$.when()` is only needed when you have more than one promise and you want to be notified when they are all done.  Otherwise, just use `.then()` or `.done()` directly on the promise.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is this part of your code:

```
for(var i=0; i<dbResult.rows.length; i++) {
  // For each producItem get tariffs
  var dbRow = dbResult.rows.item(i);  
  var data = [];

  $.when(bookings.getTariffByProductItem(dbRow.prit_cd_item))
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log("Product Item: " + dbRow.prit_st_name + " - tariffsArray: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      productItems.push({ "row": dbRow, "tariffs": data });
  });
}
def.resolve(productItems);
```

You call `def.resolve(productItems);` directly after the loop but inside of the loop you have `$.when(bookings.getTariffByProductItem(dbRow.prit_cd_item))` which is async and would not block the loop and therefore will be executed after you call the `def.resolve(productItems);`

Another problem is that `dbRow`  will be the same for all of your `.then()` callbacks because those are executed after the loop is finished.

If you plan to use Promises in a *complex* way (including loops) all over your code, then I would suggest to use a *complete* promise library and not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ANy suggestion about any library? I'm developing a jQuery Mobile app with Cordova. I'm looking into Q or when.

Comment: @JoséLuisGallego I started with `when` but currently migrated all my projects to use `bluebird`. Personally I think it is the better choice. On additional point was that bluebird uses `Promise.` as prefix in its documentation, like you would do when you use it natively in current browsers, `when` on the other hand uses `when.` as prefix in the documentation. While you could choose the _prefix_  yourself it is - in my opinion - a bad choice to use the vendor name as Prefix for a standard in the docs.